# Pandas - iterating DataFrame rows efficiently and getting values by column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Iterating in Pandas is notoriously inefficient, and best avoid whenever possible (using apply for data manipulation, etc.). In my case, unfortunately, it is unavoidable.

While it is [wildly known](https://www.stackabuse.com/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe/) that the most efficient way to do this is [itertuples](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html), with that function accessing the column data using the str name of the tuple throws the following error:

> TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

[Some](https://blog.softhints.com/pandas-iterrows-typeerror-tuple-indices-must-integers-slices) suggest that the solution to this problem is to just switch to [iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html), but as mentioned previously, this is not efficient.

How do I utilize itertuples, while still using the str name of the column to get its row value?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, one just needs to use the index of the required column instead. Since the first value in the tuple is the Index from the originating dataframe, one can use the column index from the original dataframe, and add one to account for the index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(some_data)
col_idx = df.columns.get_loc('col name') + 1  # +1 to account for the tuple Index
for row in training_df.itertuples():
        val = row[col_idx]
        print(val)
```

This solution may not be the most elegant option, but it works :)